# Android cordova app crashes when installed from the play store

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

**Issue**
Android app built on Cordova crashes/is unresponsive when installed via the Play store.

**Details**
When my android app is installed from the Play store, there's a login page. When I enter my details to login, it becomes unresponsive.

This didn't happen before. I made some minor changes to the codebase and when I updated the apk, this issue showed up.

**Techstack**
Android app based on Cordova.
Running Framework 7 along with Vue and Vuex
These are the Cordova plugins I'm using:

- Cordova version 8.1.2
- Cordova Android platform 7.0.0
- cordova-plugin-network-information ^2.0.1
- cordova-plugin-whitelist ^1.3.3
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser ^3.0.0
- onesignal-cordova-plugin ^2.4.3
- cordova-plugin-google-analytics ^1.8.6

**Steps taken till now:**

- Installed Bugsnag but it doesn't log any error. I reckon this is because the webview crashes so it can't log any javascript errors.
- Turned on android debuggable to true and installed via Diawi(cause Play store doesn't allow us to publish apps with debuggable=true). Works fine in that case

**Update**
It seems like the app crashes just when the user logs in. Which means it has something to do with the js code, but I can't debug it because remote debugging is not available for published apps.

Answer (score 1):

**I think I've found the issue.**

Basically, the android app goes kaput if it makes a ajax call to a website who's ssl cert is broken. This issue is greatly aggrevated by the fact that the app won't throw any error whatsover and this only happens in the signed versions of the app(bugsnag is no help either) installed through google play(I've enabled google keystone signin tho)

You can use things like [sslchecker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to check any problems with ssl certs. In my case the ssl cert was valid but it couldn't resolve the root cert. Installing a intermediate certificate(inside apache vhosts config under ssl chain) on the server fixed the issue.

**Update**
Android caches the ssl so it still won't work until you clear your app cache from the settings/app page and reinstall the app.

Now authentication is working but if the credentials are wrong it won't work.